# How do you move a unique_ptr out of an vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I would like to move a `unique_ptr<Foo>` out of a `vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>`. Consider my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
  int x;
  Foo(int x): x(x) {};
  ~Foo() {
    cout << "Destroy of id: " << x << "\n";
    x = -1;
  };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  auto foos = vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>();
  foos.push_back(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(100)));
  foos.push_back(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(101)));
  foos.push_back(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(102)));

  // Print all
  cout << "Vector size: " << foos.size() << "\n";
  for (auto i = foos.begin(); i != foos.end(); ++i) {
    cout << (*i)->x << "\n";
  }

  // Move Foo(100) out of the vector
  {
    auto local = move(foos.at(0));
    cout << "Removed element: " << local->x << "\n";
  }

  // Print all! Fine right?
  cout << "Vector size: " << foos.size() << "\n";
  for (auto i = foos.begin(); i != foos.end(); ++i) {
    cout << (*i)->x << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I expected that it would yield:

```
Vector size: 3
100
101
102
Removed element: 100
Destroy of id: 100
Vector size: 2
101
102
```

But instead, I get this result:

```
Vector size: 3
100
101
102
Removed element: 100
Destroy of id: 100
Vector size: 3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is my vector size still 3, and why am I getting a segmentation fault? How can I get my desired result?

Comment: The vector isn't broken. You can check the unique_ptr before de-referencing it. But you choose not to.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've posted clearly the desired output I want. What more do you want?

Comment: Based on what you've said, you don't want to move anything, you're really just looking to copy

Comment: I want you to ask a clear, to the point question.

Comment: You have a vector of (smart) pointers. After the move, one of the pointers is not valid anymore (becomes `nullptr`). Trying to dereference it is UB. It is no different from doing a `v[0] = nullptr` in a `vector<int*> v;` and then trying to dereference `*v[0]`. The behaviour is consistent, there's nothing wrong with `std::move`, the vector is not "broken", it is how is should be. Your only chance is to re-allocate the vector, but in this case you can just copy.

Comment: @Doug, it might help to present the question differently. You have already, successfully, moved the pointer out of the vector. Therefore, you should not ask any more about how to move pointers. Instead, you should ask about how to erase the old entry from the vector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's simplify your question down to:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
foos.push_back(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(100)));
auto local = std::move(foos[0]);
std::cout << foos[0]->x << '\n';
```

After you create `local` by moving `foos[0]`, `foos[0]` no longer has ownership of a pointer. It is empty. Dereferencing it becomes undefined behavior, which in your case exhibits as a segmentation fault. The `vector` is perfectly "intact" at this point, it contains one empty `unique_ptr`, and is equivalently in the state:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> foos(1);
```

You should simply *check* that your `unique_ptr` owns a pointer before dereferencing it:

```
if (foos[0]) {
    // we wouldn't get here
    std::cout << foos[0]->x << '\n';
}
```

Alternatively, since you want to enforce the invariant that your `vector` only contains valid pointers, as part of your move-from operation you should just `erase` that element:

```
auto local = std::move(foos[0]);
foos.erase(foos.begin());
// now foos is empty
```